# Swift: More elegant way to write this array mapping?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to write this:

```
struct S {
    var state: [String: Any] 

    public var amounts: [Amount] {
        var result: [Amount] = []
        (self.state["amounts"] as? [Any]?)??.forEach({ a in
            result.append(Amount(a))
        })
        return result
    }      
}

struct Amount {
    init(_ any: Any?) {}
}
```

I have tried using `map` for array, but I can't find a way to do so.

Comment: The value of `amounts` is most likely something more specific than `[Any]`

Comment: Since `amounts` array would be filled based on *optional* value from `state`, I'd suggest to declare it as an optional array (`[Amount]?`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use `guard let` and early return, which would make it look bit better.

Here is how I did it,

```
struct S {

    var state: [String: Any]

    public var amounts: [Amount] {
        guard let amounts = state["amounts"] as? [Any] else {
            return []
        }

        return amounts.map(Amount.init)
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree with this. Very swifty approach and easy to understand compared to the other answers.

Comment: Do you think that `map(Amount.init)` would be more readable than `.map { Amount($0) }`?

Comment: That depends on people to people. I would assume that OP would know basic swift syntax. For me map(Amount.init) is certainly readable and shorter than the one with complete closure.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct S {
    var state: [String: Any]
    public var amounts: [Amount] {
        return (self.state["amounts"] as? [Any] ?? []).map({ Amount($0) })
    }
}

struct Amount {
    init(_ any: Any?) {}
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Amount' to closure result type '[Amount]'`

Comment: @Rob replace return with `return (self.state["amounts"] as? [Any] ?? []).map({ Amount($0) })`

Answer (score 2):

You are using too many unnecessary optionals here. You should always use `as?` with a non-optional type. And instead of `forEach`, use `map`:

```
public var amounts: [Amount] {
    if let anyArray = self.state["amounts"] as? [Any] {
        return anyArray.map(Amount.init)
    } else {
        return []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that working in a single line,

```
public var amounts: [Amount] {
    return (self.state["amounts"] as? [Any])?.map({ Amount($0) }) ?? []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
init(_ state: [Amount]) {
    self.init()
    guard let amounts = state["amounts"] as? [Any] else {
        return []
    }

    return amounts.map(Amount.init)
}
```